# Remove Text Decoration from Bootstrap Carousel Link When in Hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, text-decorations

I can't remove the underline decoration in the caption link when in hover mode. I am using the Bootstrap Carousel. Maybe someone could help? Thanks in advance. Here is my html and css code:

```
<!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active" id="image">
            <img src="images/1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="1">
            <div class="carousel-caption" id="caption_1"> <a href="1.html">
              <h1><span>1</span></h1></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item" id="image">
            <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="2">
            <div class="carousel-caption" id="caption_2"> <a href="2.html">
              <h1><span>2</span></h1></a>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>


a h1 span {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #337EC0;
opacity: 0.75;
padding: 5px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;
```

}

```
a h1 span:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #337EC0;
opacity: 0.95;
```

}

Comment: a:hover span { ... }

Comment: Thanks, I solved this way: a:hover {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none; 
}

h1 span:hover {
 background-color: #337EC0;
 opacity: 0.95;
}